# which algorithm use pyhton shaply library to detect points in polygon?

Tags: polygon, point, shapely

Which algorithm does Shapely use to detect whether points are inside a polygon? I checked the documentation but couldn't find any specific algorithm mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shapely uses the [GEOS](https://libgeos.org) library under the hood, so if you want to know the algorythm you can check out the GEOS source code:

> Shapely is a Python package for set-theoretic analysis and
> manipulation of planar features using functions from the well known
> and widely deployed GEOS library. GEOS, a port of the Java Topology
> Suite (JTS), is the geometry engine of the PostGIS spatial extension
> for the PostgreSQL RDBMS. The designs of JTS and GEOS are largely
> guided by the Open Geospatial Consortium’s Simple Features Access
> Specification [1] and Shapely adheres mainly to the same set of
> standard classes and operations.

Source: [shapely user manual, introduction](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)